# Can mercurial rebase delete a branch?

Tags: mercurial, branch, rebase

This is the summary of a hg session:

```
> hg branch dev
marked working directory as branch dev
(branches are permanent and global, did you want a bookmark?)
> hg branch
dev
> hg ci -m 'test'
> hg update default
3 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
> hg pull --rebase
pulling from ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/repo
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 3 changesets with 44 changes to 44 files (+1 heads)
saved backup bundle to C:\repo\.hg\strip-backup\edc5f75b39d1-backup.hg
```

The problem is that after all of this, there is no trace whatsoever of the 'dev' branch. I can't make any sense of it. I committed a changeset when in the dev branch so it must have been saved. How is it possible to disappear? Could rebase delete it somehow?

EDIT: just to clarify the 'test' commit is there, but it's in the 'default' branch

Comment: "The problem is that after all of this, there is no trace whatsoever of the 'dev' branch" --- how do you know that? `hg branches` ? PS: personally I wouldn't do `pull --rebase` ever

Comment: I know because I checked :) hg branches only shows 'default'. What's wrong with pull --rebase?

Comment: I don't believe the branch disappeared. What's wrong - I just like managing changesets by myself ;-)

Comment: "just to clarify the 'test' commit is there, but it's in the 'default' branch" --- there is a chance that rebase both rebased incoming changesets and changeset from `dev`

Comment: That sounds like something that shouldn't happen at all. I'm trying to replicate without success for now.

Comment: indeed. That's why I don't believe that ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally able to reproduce it!

Your named branch branches off of a *local* changeset on the default branch.

When you run `pull --rebase` it inserts the pulled changesets into the tree and then rebases your local change sets from the default branch onto the pulled default changesets.

Since your branch `dev` branches off of that local change set, it is rebased as well. Furthermore, since you can't pass `--keepbranches` to `pull --rebase`, you lose the branch name.

To prevent that from happening, branch `dev` off of a public changeset or run rebase manually with `--keepbranches`.

Comment: Thanks Edward, I can confirm now I'm getting the same thing - if I branch off a local changeset, the branch is deleted. Public - no problem. Though, I still don't understand why this behavior is the default rather than --keepbranches.